# AnimatedStateListDrawable shows incorrect animation

Tags: android, animation

I want to make an animated drawable that animates while selected/unselected or not. There are different animation for "selected" -> "not selected" and "not selected" -> "selected" My problem is when i select my view, it triggers the right animation, but when i unselect it triggers the same animation in reverse instead of the correct one. Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- provide a different drawable for each state-->
<item
    android:id="@+id/not_selected"
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/vector_bars" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/selected"
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/vector_arrow" />



<!-- specify a transition -->
<transition
    android:fromId="@id/selected"
    android:toId="@id/not_selected"
    android:drawable="@drawable/anim_arrow_to_bars"
    android:reversible="false"/>

<transition
    android:fromId="@id/not_selected"
    android:toId="@id/selected"
    android:drawable="@drawable/anim_bars_to_arrow"
    android:reversible="false"/>

</animated-selector>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after a more extensive search i found an answer. I added 2 additional states and changed the transitions a bit and it works as intended now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- provide a different drawable for each state-->
<item
    android:id="@+id/not_selected_pressed"
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/vector_bars" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/selected_pressed"
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/vector_arrow" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/not_selected"
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/vector_bars" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/selected"
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/vector_arrow" />



<!-- specify a transition -->
<transition
    android:fromId="@id/selected_pressed"
    android:toId="@id/not_selected"
    android:drawable="@drawable/anim_arrow_to_bars"
    android:reversible="false"/>

<transition
    android:fromId="@id/selected_pressed"
    android:toId="@id/selected"
    android:drawable="@drawable/anim_bars_to_arrow"
    android:reversible="false"/>

</animated-selector>
```